# How to place dots around a center point in 2D?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, 2d, point

I'm stuck at this Problem:
I have a 2D space from Coordinates -200,-200 (upper left) to 200,200 (bottom right).

Now i wanna add a point around the center (0,0) at a random position.
So far, so good. Just have to pick a random number from -200 to 200 for each x and y.

This should now be repeated until i have the desired amount of points.

But there are two Problems now:

1. I dont want two points to be at the same position. Is there any easier of faster way, than testing each point and if neccessary repeat the whole process?
2. I dont want the points to instantly spread over the whole map. They should gather at the center and move away only as soon as there is only some space left in the biggest "ring" of points around the center.
   But nonetheless the points should have some empty spaces between them from time to time.

The last condition is my biggest Problem. Does anyone have an idea how i can solve this?

At the moment im trying to do this in javascript, but if this works, i wanna save the points in a database with mysql and add one after another with php.

Comment: *"I dont want two points to be at the same position. Is there any easier of faster way, than testing each point and if neccessary repeat the whole process?"* Store a array with generated points and check if the point does not exists..

Comment: The second problem is harder to solve it sounds a bit like the [Eight queens puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) chess problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to avoid some sort of duplicate detection for a generated point unless you generate the entire map at once by iterating through every point and turn it on based upon the outcome of a random number.  You can weight the chance of an appearance of a point based upon a distance formula from the center.

But, in general, there is nothing wrong with a Monte Carlo approach where you just generate an approximately normal distribution of points around the center.  You can do this by just getting 3 random numbers for x and for y, adding them together and dividing by 3.  This will give you a normal point cloud around the center.  You can just throw out any duplicates.